# WooCommerce checkout page change Your order details Shipping text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, gettext

[image: check this image]

woocommerce checkout page change Your order details Shipping text label.
i want attached image please check it

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [WordPress **`gettex()`** function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) that will replace the concerned text in checkout page:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'customizing_checkout_text', 10, 3 );
function customizing_checkout_text( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain )
{
    if ( $untranslated_text == 'Shipping' && is_checkout() ) {
        $translated_text = __( 'Here goes your custom text', $domain );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to resolve your issue:

Put this code in your theme's function.php file.

```
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_shipping');

function translate_shipping($translated) {
  $translated = str_ireplace('Shipping', 'Your Custom Text', $translated);
  return $translated;
}
```